# Android Parcelable with Tree of Generic Types

Tags: java, android, inheritance, parcelable, parcel

How to write `Parcelable` for a tree like structure that has a `Base` class with two implementations, one a `Node` type and the other a `Container` Type which contains a list of `Base` types.

Sorry for the mass of code below. The basic data structure is small but I have in included my current `Parcelable` implementation which is not working.

I have tried adding a byte in the base `writeToParcel` which signals which type to create when unparceling but the does not seem to work.

The problem is I am getting different data back when I parcel a `Base` object that contains a deep tree of `Container` objects.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Also any ideas on how to implemented unit tests for `Parcelable`s would be appreciated.

**Base Class**

```
public abstract class Base implements Parcelable {
    public int val;
    protected Base(final int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (this instanceof NodeBase ? 0 : 1));
        dest.writeInt(this.val);
    }

    protected Base(Parcel in) {
        this.val = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Base> CREATOR = new Creator<Base>() {
        @Override
        public Base createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return source.readByte() == 0 ? new NodeBase(source) : new ContainerBase(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Base[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Base[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Node Class**

```
public class NodeBase extends Base {

    public final String name;

    public NodeBase(final int val, final String name) {
        super(val);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
    }

    protected NodeBase(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        this.name = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<NodeBase> CREATOR = new Creator<NodeBase>() {
        @Override
        public NodeBase createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new NodeBase(source);
        }

        @Override
        public NodeBase[] newArray(int size) {
            return new NodeBase[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Container Class**

```
public class ContainerBase extends Base {
    public final  List<Base> baseList;

    public ContainerBase(final int val, final List<Base> baseList) {
        super(val);
        this.baseList = baseList;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeTypedList(this.baseList);
        dest.writeInt(this.val);
    }

    protected ContainerBase(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        this.baseList = in.createTypedArrayList(Base.CREATOR);
        this.val = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<ContainerBase> CREATOR = new Creator<ContainerBase>() {
        @Override
        public ContainerBase createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ContainerBase(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ContainerBase[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContainerBase[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Generic Types, but I do not see any Generic Types being used in your code. All I see are Parent and Child inherited classes. But assuming that your Node and Container are generic and that they have a generic parameter **T**, where T can be any object that can be stored in your Node/Container, then the following solution should help:

**Step 1**. Store the classes that extends from your Generic classes as a string in your base class:

```
public abstract class Base implements Parcelable {
    private String containerClassName;
    private String nodeClassName;
```

**Step 2**. Make sure that your generic classes call super(), which you have already done.

**Step 3**. Any classes that extends from your generic classes must specify the  class name during its construction like this:

```
public class NewNode extends NodeBase {

    public NodeBase() {
        super();
        setClassNames(NewNode.class.getName()); // Base class setter method
    }
```

**Step 4**. In your base class, you can then read/write your class names to getClassLoader() like this:

```
protected NodeBase(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    this.containerClassName = in.readString();
    this.nodeClassName = in.readString();

    ClassLoader containerLoader;
    ClassLoader nodeLoader;
    try {
        containerLoader = Class.forName(containerClassName).getClassLoader();
        nodeLoader = Class.forName(nodeClassName).getClassLoader();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    containerObject = in.readParcelable(containerLoader);
    nodeObject = in.readParcelable(nodeLoader);
    //... Other class members can go here
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeString(containerClassName);
    dest.writeString(nodeClassName);
    //... Other class members can go here
}
```